# spring & maven modular web servise with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a modular web app with a separate web service. I started with the entities, then DAO, then service and in the end Web service module. I have a parent module and the pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ba.app<groupId>
<artifactId>Base_app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Base_app</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>    
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>Base_entity</module> 
    <module>Base_dao</module> 
    <module>Base_service</module> 
    <module>Base_ws</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.179</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.32</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And the web service pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent> 
    <groupId>ba.app</groupId> 
    <artifactId>Base_app</artifactId> 
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
</parent> 
<groupId>ba.app</groupId>
<artifactId>Base_ws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <start-class>com.app.rest.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <!-- <repository> -->
    <!-- <id>springsource-repo</id> -->
    <!-- <name>SpringSource Repository</name> -->
    <!-- <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url> -->
    <!-- </repository> -->
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
     <dependency> 
        <groupId>ba.app</groupId> 
        <artifactId>Base_dao</artifactId> 
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
        <groupId>ba.app</groupId> 
        <artifactId>Base_entity</artifactId> 
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ba.app</groupId> 
        <artifactId>Base_service</artifactId> 
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
     </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Base_web_service_app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

If I comment the parent tag

```
<!-- <parent> 
    <groupId>ba.app</groupId> 
    <artifactId>Base_app</artifactId> 
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
</parent> -->
```

everything works fine. Maybe the spring in the Parent module and in the ws module are not compatible? I work with java 1.7. If I try to deploy this version the stack trace looks like this:

```
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Base_ws_app' did not find a matching property.
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 1 2015 22:30:46 UTC
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.30.0
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\App\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\runtimes\apache-tomcat-8.0.30
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\App\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\runtimes\apache-tomcat-8.0.30
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\App\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\runtimes\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\endorsed
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;%M2%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;.
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1127 ms
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:24 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@111e1d7b, com.app.rest.Application@50217f04]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Base_ws_app]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Base_wes_app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.createSpringApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createSpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2494)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:405)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 27 more

Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 27, 2016 6:18:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

I need the spring dependencies in the parent because all other modules need the spring dependencies...

> **Edit**

I changed to java 8 and tried to that my parent have a spring boot starter parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

but i get the same error...
I tried with the same configuration in the parent and get the same error...

Comment: why don't you configure spring boot in the parent itself ?

Comment: You are missing a JAR with .tld declarations.  I would make Spring Boot the parent as well.  Why not REST and Thymeleaf?

Comment: I tried to configure boot in the parent but the same stack trace...